# Converting code with Boolean to a byte array

Tags: arduino, clock, rtc

I am having a hard time understanding this code. I have code I am working on to sequentially flash the current 12 hr time on a single 7-seg display when you press a button.

I used a Boolean matrix to assign numbers to segments. Someone suggested that I use a byte array to save on memory but I am having a hard time integrating it into my code to function correctly.

Here is my code:

```
#include "RTClib.h"
RTC_DS1307 rtc;
const int buttonPin = 9;  //user input
int buttonState = 0;      //remove uncertainty
int8_t pinSegA = 6;       //7-segment display input pins
int8_t pinSegB = 7;       //7-segment display input pins
int8_t pinSegC = 8;       //7-segment display input pins
int8_t pinSegD = 2;       //7-segment display input pins
int8_t pinSegE = 3;       //7-segment display input pins
int8_t pinSegF = 5;       //7-segment display input pins
int8_t pinSegG = 4;       //7-segment display input pins
// Segment                 a  b  c  d  e  f  g     // Digit
boolean digits [10] [7] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,    // 0
                           0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,    // 1
                           1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,    // 2
                           1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,    // 3
                           0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,    // 4
                           1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,    // 5
                           1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,    // 6
                           1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,    // 7
                           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,    // 8
                           1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, }; // 9
void setup () {
  if (! rtc.begin()) {2;   //RTC check
    abort();
  }
  pinMode (pinSegA, OUTPUT);  //IO definitions
  pinMode (pinSegB, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode (pinSegC, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode (pinSegD, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode (pinSegE, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode (pinSegF, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode (pinSegG, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);  
}
void displayDigit(uint8_t digit) {
  digitalWrite(pinSegA, digits[digit][0]);  //assigns numerals to the matrix
  digitalWrite(pinSegB, digits[digit][1]);
  digitalWrite(pinSegC, digits[digit][2]);
  digitalWrite(pinSegD, digits[digit][3]);
  digitalWrite(pinSegE, digits[digit][4]);
  digitalWrite(pinSegF, digits[digit][5]);
  digitalWrite(pinSegG, digits[digit][6]);
  delay(1100);
  digitalWrite(pinSegA, LOW); //clears any persistant lit segments (needed for code to work)
  digitalWrite(pinSegB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinSegC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinSegD, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinSegE, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinSegF, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinSegG, LOW);
}
void loop () {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();   //defines time in library
  int minutes = now.minute();   //defines minutes
  int tens = minutes / 10;    //parsing tens and ones place from minutes
  int ones = minutes % 10;
  int hours = now.hour();   //defines hours
  int tenss = hours / 10;   //parsing tens and ones place from hours
  int oness = hours % 10;
  int hoursss = hours - 12;   //variable for 12 hr time
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);   //checks button high or low
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    if (hours >= 12) {   //12 hour time logic
      displayDigit(hoursss);
    } else if (hours < 12) {
      if (tenss > 0) {      //removes zero from tens place so AM time only shows 3 digits
        displayDigit(tenss);
        delay(250);
      } 
      displayDigit(oness);
    }
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(pinSegG, HIGH);    //shows hyphen to replace normal colon
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(pinSegG, LOW);     //shows hyphen to replace normal colon
    delay(250);
    displayDigit(tens);
    delay(250);
    displayDigit(ones);
    delay(250);
    if (hours >= 12) {               //diplays P for PM
      digitalWrite(pinSegA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pinSegB, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pinSegE, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pinSegF, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pinSegG, HIGH);  
    } else if (hours < 12) {        //displays A for AM
      digitalWrite(pinSegA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pinSegB, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pinSegC, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pinSegE, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pinSegF, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pinSegG, HIGH);
    }
    delay(1100);
    digitalWrite(pinSegA, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinSegB, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinSegC, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinSegD, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinSegE, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinSegF, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinSegG, LOW); 
  }
}
```

The code suggested to me to replace my matrix is:

```
const byte LetterA = 10;
const byte LetterP = 11;
const byte Blank = 12;

byte digits [13] =
{
  0b01111110,   // 0
  0b00110000,   // 1
  0b01101101,   // 2
  0b01111001,   // 3
  0b00110011,   // 4
  0b01011011,   // 5
  0b01011111,   // 6
  0b01110000,   // 7
  0b01111111,   // 8
  0b01110011,   // 9
  0b01110111,   // LetterA
  0b01100111,   // LetterP
  0b00000000,   // Blank
}; // null
```

Comment: So what is wrong with the suggested code?

Comment: You'll have to bit shift off the bits from the byte to set the individual IO.

Comment: Arduino software surely CANT be that primitive that you have to write one bit at a time? Just write a byte to the whole 8 bit port your display is connected to.

Comment: I don't know how to incorporate the suggested code into mine and make it work, I am relatively inexperienced with these more complex arduino function (complex to a casual user). I am only seeking the suggested route because memory space is a concern for future evolutions of the project and I was told that byte arrays use much less memory than Boolean matrices,

Comment: to get bit `m` from a number `n` you can `(n >> m) & 1`.

Comment: @user_1818839 the default API is one bit at a time for IO.  There are libraries that will do 8 bits at a time.  Google knows all!

Comment: A new suggestion I got was to go about it this way: `
void setup ()
{
  if (! rtc.begin())
  {
    abort();
  }
  for (int s = 0; s < 7; s++)
  {
    digitalWrite(SegmentPins[s], LOW);
    pinMode (SegmentPins[s], OUTPUT);  
  }
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}
void displayDigit(uint8_t digit)
{
  for (int s = 0; s < 7; s++)
  {
    digitalWrite(SegmentPins[s], digits[digit] & (0b01000000 >> s));
  }
  delay(1100);
  for (int s = 0; s < 7; s++)
  {
    digitalWrite(SegmentPins[s], LOW);
  }
}`

Comment: @Aaron I was sure there would be such a library : hope the OP can find it. (I've always bypassed Arduino's own software, preferring other tools)

Comment: The question has really nothing to do with RTC, clock, or even arduino, or embedded systems. This is rather generic C question, as you don't even need C++ to make the change from boolean array to byte array.

Answer (score 0):

This code works identically to my original code but saves 218 bytes of compiled memory by using an array rather than a matrix:

```
#include "RTClib.h"
RTC_DS1307 rtc;
const int buttonPin = 9;  //user input
int buttonState = 0;      //remove button float value
const byte SegmentPins[] = {6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 5, 4};
const byte LetterA = 10;
const byte LetterP = 11;
const byte Blank = 12;

byte digits [13] =
{
  0b01111110,   // 0
  0b00110000,   // 1
  0b01101101,   // 2
  0b01111001,   // 3
  0b00110011,   // 4
  0b01011011,   // 5
  0b01011111,   // 6
  0b01110000,   // 7
  0b01111111,   // 8
  0b01110011,   // 9
  0b01110111,   // LetterA
  0b01100111,   // LetterP
  0b00000000,   // Blank
};

void setup ()
{

  if (! rtc.begin())
  {
    abort();
  }
  
  for (int s = 0; s < 7; s++)
  {
    digitalWrite(SegmentPins[s], LOW);
    pinMode (SegmentPins[s], OUTPUT);  
  }

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

}
void displayDigit(uint8_t digit)
{

  for (int s = 0; s < 7; s++)
  {
    digitalWrite(SegmentPins[s], digits[digit] & (0b01000000 >> s));
  }

  delay(1100);

  for (int s = 0; s < 7; s++)
  {
    digitalWrite(SegmentPins[s], LOW);
  }

}
void loop ()

{
  DateTime now = rtc.now();   //defines time in library
  int minutes = now.minute();   //defines minutes
  int tens = minutes / 10;    //parsing tens and ones place from minutes
  int ones = minutes % 10;
  int hours = now.hour();   //defines hours
  int tenss = hours / 10;   //parsing tens and ones place from hours
  int oness = hours % 10;
  int hoursss = hours - 12;   //variable for 12 hr time

  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
  {
    if (hours >= 12)    //12 hour time logic
    {
      displayDigit(hoursss);
    }
    else if (hours < 12)
        {
      if (tenss > 0)        //removes superfluous zero from tens place so AM time only shows 3 digits
      {
        displayDigit(tenss);

        delay(250);
      }
      displayDigit(oness);
    }

    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(SegmentPins[6], HIGH);    //shows hyphen to replace normal colon
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(SegmentPins[6], LOW);     //shows hyphen to replace normal colon
    delay(250);

    displayDigit(tens);
    delay(250);

    displayDigit(ones);
    delay(250);

    if (hours >= 12)                //diplays P for PM
    {
      displayDigit(LetterP);
    }
    else if (hours < 12)            //displays A for AM
    {
      displayDigit(LetterA);
    }

    delay(1100);
    
    displayDigit(Blank);
  }
}
```

Comment: Austin Fox - Hi, Thanks for coming back with the answer to your question. In order to mark the topic as solved, please "[accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)" your answer (click the "tick mark" next to your answer, to turn it green). Then it is shown as having an accepted answer in various lists here, and we don't get nagged for it being a question with an unaccepted answer. Since [you must wait 48 hours after you asked the question](/help/self-answer) before you can accept your own answer, you can accept it any time after 17:49 UTC on November 24. Thanks.